# jQuery tabs without the wrapper/container div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to add this in Content Management System where each editor box has a char. limit of 4000. I cannot fit all my content div inside, I need to put each tab content div in a separate editor box. That's why I need to get rid of the wrapper div.

I have the following tab script WITH wrapper div "tabs":

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#t1">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#t2">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#t3">three</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="t1">a lot of content</div>
  <div id="t2">a lot of content</div>
  <div id="t3">a lot of content</div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');

    $('div.tabs ul.nav a').click(function () {
    tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

    $('div.tabs ul.nav a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

---

My idea was to add a common class "series1" to each of my content in order to archive the same effect but doesn't work: (am a jquery noob)

```
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#t1">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#t2">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#t3">three</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="t1" class="series1">content</div>
  <div id="t2" class="series1">content</div>
  <div id="t3" class="series1">content</div>
```

---

```
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.series1');

    $('ul.nav a').click(function () {
    tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

    $('ul.nav a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

It doesn't matter if I have to manually mention the individual id/class name in the jQuery, someone could help me to make this work?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What's the problem with having a `div` around the `ul`?

Comment: Am adding these code in a Content Management System and each editor box has a char. limit of 4000. I cannot fit all my content inside. That's why I need to put each tab content div in a separate editor box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of functionality is quite easy to implement in jQuery without `.tabs()`, take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUt9Z/1/) for some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Tom! If I have two or more sets of tabs in one page, how would you modify it? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Pretty sure there is a simpler way but in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/WUt9Z/4/) I have used `.filter()` which returns true on the correct element that I want to remove `.show` from.